# Filling a page with a div background without a scroll bar

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want a `div` of class "panel" and white background to stretch to the bottom of the viewable area and without displaying a scroll bar (only show the scroll bar when content is more than viewport)

Here is the example I was working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/VUP72/

I tried :

```
.panel{
  height: 100%;
}
```

But the scroll will appear since it's 100% + header. How do I fill the page without the scroll bar?

Comment: May be you can find this interesting: [http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/sticky-header-and-footer-using-css/]

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your css:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This way you will NEVER get scrollbars. Another way is using calc:

```
.panel {
    min-height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Change 20px in the height of the header. 
I'm not sure if this works in all browsers but you'd have to try that.

Comment: that would cause any additional text to be cut off when it does overflow (or on smaller resolutions)

Comment: That is correct. If that is actually an issue Javascript is the way to go.

Comment: JavaScript is not the way to go! Don't fix with JS what you broke with CSS - Your karma will plummet beyond redemption

Comment: Looking a css solution, and without hidding the text . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if u can do this in simple css cause every monitor has a different height so i think you should use something like javascript or jquery to get the height of the monitor and when it goes out of that range to show you the scroll. im not really sure if this is what you're looking for

Comment: Was looking a CSS solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you could place the header **within** the main container, like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="sub-header">SUB-header</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel-top">TOP PANEL</div>
    <div class="panel">PANEL 
      <div>My contente should appear here ...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer><div id="footer">Footer</div></footer>
```

Then it will scroll with the whole page. If you don't want that, you can give the header position:static with top:0px and left:0px.

Comment: That is not what i pretend. I want to .panel stretch until bottom of page. Should only appear scroll when browser hit the content.

Answer (score 0):

remove `Height` from body. I hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: Well is not ok, it solves the scrollbar, but now how you increase bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at Flexbox, you have to be a little more creative about how you style your elements to give the illusion that a particular element is bigger than it really is.  Don't forget that your `body` element is a container and can be styled independently from the `html` element!

http://jsfiddle.net/VUP72/4/

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

html {
  min-width: 400px;
}

body {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

header, .sub-header{
  height: 30px;
}

.panel-top, .panel{
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
}

/*COLORS to indentify*/
header{ background: red; }
#footer{ background: blue;}
body{ background: white; }
.sub-header { background: grey }
.container{background: yellow;}
.panel-top{background: #f0f0f0;}
.panel{background: white;}
```